# Using MinGW built dll in a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dllimport, mingw32

I have build a dll and now I want to use this dll in a Microsoft Visual Studio project.

```
g++ -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\MyLib.o ..\src\MyLib.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,--out-implib=MyLib.lib -Wl,--output-def=MyLib.def -oMyLib.dll src\MyLib.o -lwsock32
```

The dll works fine when I use it in a "gcc project".

I have tried different methodes to create the ".lib" and ".def" files and tried to import these libs in VS by following different tutorials. But VS does not find the methodes declared in the dll...

I'm thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard about name mangling? Unless the functions exported from DLL are marked as extern "C" their names are going to be mangled in a compiler-specific way. Thus the problem.

Comment: And to make it worse, it is not only about the name mangling, also other stuff like exception handling or object memory layout is incompatible. And this is not limited to different compilers , also different versions of one compiler, or compiler invocations with different options can be incompatible to each other.

Comment: @Rudi: +1. Not to mention different implementations of the Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your dll to be used with another compiler you have the following options:

1. Expose only "C" interface (with
   extern "C") - no classes or anyting
   C++ specific.
2. Make a COM dll.
3. Make your on COM-like model that follows
   the same constraints.

Comment: I think pure abstract classes are also compiler-independent (to some extent at least).

Comment: @Pedro: That's what I meant by the option 3) although it is a little more complicated than just using abstract classes.

Comment: GCC and MSVC can both be used to make COM dlls - which is a binary interface based on having compliant implementations of virtual functions. IT should be possible to pass pure virtual classes between MSVC and GCC safely (Again, assuming the parameter types are POD or pure virtual classes)

Comment: How can I create a COM dll (Binary interface / ABI) dll using gcc? I think I use the wrong keyword because i find nothing to this topic.

Comment: @Sascha: Start from here to see how it works (although the samples use pure C it is easy to convert it to C++) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others. Have a look at
[Binary Compatible C++ Interfaces](http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html).
Its clear from the above that there is no way direct to interface C++ DLL built with MinGW with MS Visual Studio. This interfacing "works" cleanly only via C based interface.

Comment: link is dead, please change it